# Error during execution of query expression in LINQpad

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I m beginner in LINQ & I tried to create a table name `emp`& `column` `EmpID,name,Sal`to find out to list all employees who have a salary between  1000 and 2000.but when i executed in LINQPad its give error.my query Expression is

```
from e in Emps
where e.sal>1000 &&e.sal <2000
select e
```

Error

```
LINQPad.User.Emp' does not contain a definition for 'sal' and no extension method
'sal' accepting a first argument of type 'LINQPad.User.Emp' could be found 
(press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)
```

Is it my query expression wrong or something else please suggest me
Thanks

Comment: `e.Sal` instead of `e.sal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case sensitivity is important in many languages, C# is one of them. For example, these two properties are completely different:

```
public int sal { get; set; }
public int Sal { get; set; }
```

So change your query to this:

```
from e in Emps
where e.Sal > 1000 && e.Sal <2000
select e
```